# How can I slow down .avi files when creating them from Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have created a list of plots that I want to run as a movie.

```
list11 = {pic0, pic001, pic01, pic02, pic05, pic1, pic2, pic5, pic10};
```

First I created an animation which I slowed down to 1 frame per second using the following code:

```
ListAnimate[list11, AnimationRate -> 1]
```

I now wanted to export this to an avi file so I tried the following:

```
Export["periodic.avi", ListAnimate[list11, 1]]
```

However the result of this was a movie that played too fast (I think it was playing at the default total duration of 5 seconds rather than the 9 that I wanted)

I then tried to export the list directly:

```
 Export["periodic2.avi", list11]
```

This however went even faster again (the whole thing was finished in about 1 second)

Looking in the help files it said that there was an advanced export option called "framerate", so I tried:

```
 Export["periodic2.avi", list11,"framerate"->1]
```

But this just gave me the exact same output as the previous .avi file (it seemed that the framrate option was completely ignored because I tried different values instead of 1 but the output was always the same speed).

Can anyone enlighten me on how I can control the animation speed of the .avi file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematica is case sensitive."framerate"  should be written as "FrameRate".

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you (normally I catch those sort of errors because the text stays blue but this doesn't apply when you're writing inside quotation marks).

Comment: -1 for not including the mma code to construct the animated gif as an avi. Thinking again ... +1 because I'm sure you are going to post it ...

Comment: @belisarius `r1 = Rasterize[Style["framerate", Bold, 72]];
r2 = Rasterize[Style["FrameRate", Bold, 72]];
fr = Table[
  Image[a ImageData[r2] + (1 - a) ImageData[r1]], {a, 0, 1, 0.1}];`. I originally thought of using `ImageCompose` but that doesn't allow an alpha for the background, or ImageAdd, but that doesn't do any alpha at all. I'm sure there must be an appropriate function for this, but I didn't feel like spending too much time on this.

Comment: @Sjoerd `r1 = Rasterize[Style["framerate", Bold, 72]]; r2 = 
 Rasterize[Style["FrameRate", Bold, 72]]; fr = 
 Table[ImageCompose[r1, {r2, a}], {a, 0, 1, 0.1}]`